# Ошибка при миграции

Tags: php, laravel

Возникает ошибка Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : syntax error, unexpec
ted ':', expecting ',' or ')'

```
$table->bigIncrements(column: 'id');
$table->integer(column: 'parent_id')->unsigned()->default(value: 0);
$table->string(column: 'slug')->unique();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если обратиться к [документации](https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/schema), то вы не правильно пользуетесь методами.

```php
$table->bigIncrements('id');
$table->integer('parent_id')->unsigned()->default(0);
$table->string('slug')->unique();
```

Если я не ошибаюсь, то должно быть так.

Comment: спасибо большое, помогло